# Is jquery_include_tag only used if not precompiling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

If I use `jquery_include_tag` is it only used when not in `production` in Rails 4 since `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` includes whatever will be made into `application.js`?

Then does `jquery_include_tag` only get used when working in `development` mode?

Comment: No, javascript include tag also add your js file in the page wherever you used jquery_include_tag and this is not only for development mode.

Comment: So it's going to be added twice if its in `config.assets.precompile` and `jquery_include_tag`?

Comment: Do you mean that its also included in application.js by config.assets.precompile?  Then yes, it will be added two time if you added it in  application.js and jquery_include_tag.